# Which "sense" of "measure" does medida refer to?

Tags: definiciones

The English translation of "medida" that I have is "measure."

This could mean "measurement" as in "length."

Or it could mean "measure" in the sense of "means," (to an end.)

Which of these two senses does "measure" take? Or is it both of them? Or others?

La traduccion ingles de "medida" que yo conozco es "measure."

Puede significa "measurement" como en "length" (largo)?

O puede significa "measure" como en "means" (to an end)?

De cuales de los dos sentidos tiene la "medida"? O ambos? O otros?

Comment: Tienes alguna expresión en la cuál hayas leido/escuchado la palabra y que es la que origina tu duda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una rápida busqueda en RAE para la palabra [medida](http://dle.rae.es/medida) te dará toda la información que necesitas sobre ella y un uso similar es con la palabra "measures" en varios de esos significados aunque quizás no para todos.

Por ejemplo:

> Tomaremos medidas para solucionar el problema. / Tomaremos acciones
>   para solucionar el problema.
>   Te ayudaré en la medida de lo posible.
>   / Te ayudaré tanto como pueda.
>   Bebe con medida. / Bebe con
>   moderación.

Si se me ocurren más ejemplos los agregaré más tarde.

Comment: also  «bebe con mesura»